# C++ Adding sum of a series

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, sum

I am trying to write a simple program to take the sum of the harmonic series for `ln(2)`, which is `(-1)^(k+1)/k`.

The problem is I keep getting stuck on adding the answers of the series together.

```
int main() {

    double n(0); 

    while (n < 1) {
        cout << "Enter n: ";
        cin >> n;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {  
        double num1 = (pow(-1.0, i + 1.0)) / (i);

        cout << num1;  
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried doing things like `double answer = num1 + num1;` expecting that the loop would just re-add itself each time it re runs through until `i` is equal to `n`, but I have not had much help. If anyone could point me in the write direction that would be great. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create a variable that keeps the running sum.
2. Initialize it to zero.
3. Keep adding each of the terms of the series to the sum.

```
double sum = 0.0;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {  
    double num1 = (pow(-1.0, i + 1.0)) / (i);
    sum += num1;
}

cout << sum << endl;
```

**Suggestion for improvement**

You don't need to compute `pow(-1.0, i+1.0)` for every term. You can keep a running `sign`.

```
int sign = -1;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++, sign = -sign) {  
    double num1 = sign*1.0 / (i);
    sum += num1;
}
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense. I knew I couldn't take an initialized variable within the loop but initializing outside the loop and reusing went right over my head. Thank you very much